# Deserialize Avro Object In Python Without Having AVRO Schema On Hand

Tags: python, avro

I would like to see an example of how I would deserialize an AVRO object in Python with out having an AVRO schema for it on hand.

I found an example below for deserializing but `avro.io.DatumReader` uses schema as input. Is it possible to extract the AVRO schema from raw_bytes?

```
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(raw_bytes)
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
decoded_data = reader.read(decoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `schema` passed into `DatumReader` is optional. If you want to read without having to supply the schema, you can create a `DatumReader()` without giving it a schema.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFileReader` should work:

```py
from avro.io import DatumReader
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
import io

raw_bytes = ... # contents of avro file
elements = DataFileReader(io.BytesIO(raw_bytes), DatumReader())
for e in elements:
    print(e)
```